# When you have multilingual content not in the Original language

Tags: i18n-l10n

Bilingual content is fine, but what do you do in Drupal 8 when you have content only in a secondary language. I've got a site in English & Japanese, with pages mostly in English (Original language), but some pages only in Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

How to create content in a secondary language:

Go to the language settings of a content type and change it from "Site's default language (English)" to a secondary language or enable

> [x] Show language selector on create and edit pages

so that the editor can select a different language for each piece of content. As long as you don't add a translation to this content it stays monolingual (in the secondary language). You can even restrict a content type to this by disabling:

> [ ] Enable translation